# Different numbers for the same footnote

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes

Can someone help me to make this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: This is actually an interesting question. The reverse has been asked many times, (i.e., "Lorem ipsum¹ dolor sit amet¹, consectetur adipiscing elit¹." with just a single footnote 1) but this seems to be a new question. It would have been better if an MWE was included but I suggest to leave open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2022/05/29**

The package and its documentation is basically finished and shall be published by 2022/05/31. Apart from the approach below, the final package also adopted a more convenient syntax proposed by @antshar. The commands are separated into two groups:

- First approach (as in this answer)
  [image]
- Second approach (proposed by @antshar in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645871/194994))
  [image]

For examples you may refer to the documentation.

---

**Update 2022/05/26:**

I've converted this into a new package `multifootnote` (combined with my answer in [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645628/194994)). The commands stated in the answer below have been renamed to `\multifootnotemark` (or still `\footnotenumber`) and `\multifootnotetext` (or simply `\multifootnote`).

When the documentation is finished, it shall be uploaded to CTAN. This is expected to be finished before June.

---

Here is an automatic version. I defined two new commands: `\footnotenumber` and `\footnotemultiple`.

- `\footnotenumber` takes one optional argument, namely the label.
- `\footnotemultiple` works similar as `\footnote`, with the optional argument here as a list of labels you wish to refer to.

Below is a complete example (if you prefer to have no hyperlink on the numbers in the footnote, simply replace `\ref` with `\ref*`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \footnotenumber { O{} }
  {
    \footnotemark
      {
        \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
          {
            \addtocounter { footnote } { -1 }
            \refstepcounter { footnote }
            \label { #1 }
          }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \footnotemultiple { O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
      {
        \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
        \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
          {
            \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { \ref{ ##1 } }
          }
        \def \thefootnote { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { , } }
      }
    \footnotetext { #2 }
    \group_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Here\footnotenumber[fn1] are\footnotenumber[fn2] some words\footnotenumber[fn3]\footnotemultiple[fn1,fn2,fn3]{Some footnote.}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

**Old answer**

You can use `\footnotemark` to produce the number, and `\footnotetext` to produce the text (`\footnote` is just the combination of them). To get the `1,2,3`, I locally redefined `\thefootnote`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Here\footnotemark{} are\footnotemark{} some words\footnotemark{}{\def\thefootnote{1,2,3}\footnotetext{Some footnote}}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

By the way, this TeX FAQ page might be helpful to you: [Footnotes whose texts are identical](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-repfootnote).

Comment: While this works it requires to keep track of the correct numbers yourself - a solution which automatically combines the different numbers would be preferred (note that I don't know how to arrive at such a solution easily).

Comment: @Marijn Yes I was aware of that. However `\ref` doesn't work with `\footnotemark` so I didn't come up with an automatic solution.

Comment: @Marijn I've updated my answer to include a new automatic solution.

Comment: Sorry, but this automatic solution doesn't work for me. A lot of errors occur, such are "! Undefined control sequence. \NewDocumentCommand \footnotenumber", "! Illegal parameter number in definition of \label@name.", "! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a." etc.

Comment: @Bolzano If you are using a LaTeX distribution older than 2020, you may need to add `\usepackage{xparse}` for using `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: Thank you so much, but now I've got another question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645628/moving-the-beginning-of-a-footnote-to-the-right).