# Moving the beginning of a footnote to the right

Tags: numbering, positioning, footnotes

I would like that the numbers "2, 3, 4, 5, 6" start from the same position as the number "1" in the previous footnote.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \footnotenumber { O{} }
  {
    \footnotemark
      {
        \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
          {
            \addtocounter { footnote } { -1 }
            \refstepcounter { footnote }
            \label { #1 }
          }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \footnotemultiple { O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
      {
        \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
        \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
          {
            \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { \ref{ ##1 } }
          }
        \def \thefootnote { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { , } }
      }
    \footnotetext { #2 }
    \group_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur\footnote{Morbi ac rhoncus mi, at porttitor erat. Aliquam fringilla erat nec tortor placerat ullamcorper.} adipiscing\footnotenumber[fn1] elit. Nunc non nisl\footnotenumber[fn2] sed orci suscipit porta\footnotenumber[fn3]. Nulla et arcu placerat\footnotenumber[fn4], vehicula lorem id, imperdiet ante. Aenean\footnotenumber[fn5] et tortor purus.

\footnotemultiple[fn1,fn2,fn3,fn4,fn5]{Etiam porttitor bibendum neque et luctus. Ut volutpat, erat vitae dapibus condimentum, eros nunc suscipit eros, id imperdiet lectus massa eget metus.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

P. S.
This way of numbering footnotes is shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645330/different-numbers-for-the-same-footnote).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2022/05/28**

There shall soon be a new package `multifootnote` on CTAN. The answer of this question corresponds to the two package options:

[image]

---

Normally the footnote is typeset with list, where the label width is fixed. However, you can completely redefine this behavior by modifying `\@makefntext`. Notice that the `@` here means that you need `\makeatletter`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{
    \parbox{0pt}{\@makefnmark} \nobreakspace #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand \footnotenumber { O{} }
  {
    \footnotemark
      {
        \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
          {
            \addtocounter { footnote } { -1 }
            \refstepcounter { footnote }
            \label { #1 }
          }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \footnotemultiple { O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
      {
        \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
        \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
          {
            \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { \ref*{ ##1 } }
          }
        \def \thefootnote { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { , } }
      }
    \footnotetext { #2 }
    \group_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur\footnote{Morbi ac rhoncus mi, at porttitor erat. Aliquam fringilla erat nec tortor placerat ullamcorper.} adipiscing\footnotenumber[fn1] elit. Nunc non nisl\footnotenumber[fn2] sed orci suscipit porta\footnotenumber[fn3]. Nulla et arcu placerat\footnotenumber[fn4], vehicula lorem id, imperdiet ante. Aenean\footnotenumber[fn5] et tortor purus.

\footnotemultiple[fn1,fn2,fn3,fn4,fn5]{Etiam porttitor bibendum neque et luctus. Ut volutpat, erat vitae dapibus condimentum, eros nunc suscipit eros, id imperdiet lectus massa eget metus.}

\end{document}
```

---

If you wish to indent the first line of each footnote, simply add a `\hspace*` in the command.

```
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{
    \hspace*{1.5em}
    \parbox{0pt}{\@makefnmark} \nobreakspace #1
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can keep the indent? So, just to move the first line of the footnote to the right.

Comment: @Bolzano You mean indenting those lines containing footnote mark (in other words, the first line of each footnote entry)?

Comment: @Bolzano I've edited my answer, let's see if this is want you want.

Comment: Yes, thank you!