# Hyperlinks of footnotes with multiple numbers/markers

Tags: macros, hyperref, footnotes, expl3, hyperlink

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645332/194994), I created two commands `\footnotenumber` and `\multifootnote` for writing footnote with multiple numbers. The problem with these commands is that hyperlinks do not work as in usual footnotes: for example, if you click on the red boxed "1" in the document generated by the code below, nothing would happen.

I tried to use `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` in these commands without success. To me the difficulties are: 1) I don't know much about the internal of `\footnotemark`, thus have no idea where to place the `\hyperlink`ed number/mark; 2) in the `\clist_put_right:Nn` line, if I use `\ref*{ ##1 }` as the text of a `\hypertarget`, there shall be multiple errors like `Undefined control sequence. \@hyper@@anchor ...r@spot {#2#3}\let \put@me@back`.

Thus my question is that, what should be done to make the hyperlinks work? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotemark { O{} }
  {
    \footnotemark
    \group_begin:
      \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
        {
          \addtocounter { footnote } { -1 }
          \refstepcounter { footnote }
          \label { #1 }
        }
    \group_end:
  }
\NewCommandCopy \footnotenumber \multifootnotemark

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetext { O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
      {
        \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
        \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
          {
            \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { \ref*{ ##1 } }
          }
        \def \thefootnote { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { , } }
      }
    \footnotetext { #2 }
    \group_end:
  }
\NewCommandCopy \multifootnote \multifootnotetext

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum\footnotenumber[fn1] dolor sit amet\footnotenumber[fn2], consectetur adipiscing elit\footnotenumber[fn3].
\multifootnote[fn1,fn2,fn3]{Test footnote.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why having different footnote-marks associated to the same footnote-text instead of just repeating the same footnote-mark? S.th. like:  Lorem ipsum 1 dolor sit amet 1, consectetur adipiscing elit 1  ... 1 Test footnote.

Comment: @UlrichDiez To me it's clearer how many places share this same footnote. And I believe this would make it a little easier for readers to locate the footnote marks on the page.

Comment: So it is about backward-referencing... I see. Thanks for the explanation. I don't know what I was thinking. :-(  Please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotemark { O{} }
  {
    \footnotemark
    \group_begin:
      \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
        {
          \addtocounter { footnote } { -1 }
          \refstepcounter { footnote }
          \global\let\@currentHref\Hy@footnote@currentHref
          \label { #1 }
        }
    \group_end:
  }
\NewCommandCopy \footnotenumber \multifootnotemark

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetext { O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
      {
        \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
        \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
          {
            \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 
             { \ref*{ ##1 } }
            \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_clist
             { \hypertarget{\getrefbykeydefault{##1}{anchor}{Doc-Start}}{} } 
          }
        \def \thefootnote { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { , } }
      }
    \xdef\Hy@footnote@currentHref{x\Hy@footnote@currentHref}  
    \footnotetext { \clist_use:Nn\l_tmpb_clist{}\ignorespaces #2 }
    \group_end:
  }
\NewCommandCopy \multifootnote \multifootnotetext

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum\footnotenumber[fn1] dolor sit amet\footnotenumber[fn2], consectetur adipiscing elit\footnotenumber[fn3].
\multifootnote[fn1,fn2,fn3]{\label{blub}Test footnote.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works greatly! Would you mind explaining a little on why this would work? Also, there is a problem occurs to me: since `hyperref` might not be loaded by the user, is there some way (like a conditional) so that the code can fall back to my original version when `hyperref` is not loaded?

Comment: Another question: may I ask what `\xdef\Hy@footnote@currentHref{x\Hy@footnote@currentHref}` is for? The code still seems to work fine without this line.

Comment: Note: `\clist_clear:N \l_tmpb_clist` is missing. @Jinwen `\footnotetext` sets an anchor (i.e. a hyperlink target) named according to `\Hy@footnote@currentHref`. After, e.g., a `\footnotemark` that produces note number 3, `\Hy@footnote@currentHref` contains `Hfootnote.3`. However, after at least 2 compilations, the `\getrefbykeydefault` call for label `fn3` also retrieves the anchor name `Hfootnote.3`, therefore the `\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { }` call in the arg of `\footnotetext` will already define anchor `Hfootnote.3`.

Comment: @Jinwen Thus, after 2 compilations and without the `\xdef \Hy@footnote@currentHref { x\Hy@footnote@currentHref }`, there would be a duplicate anchor (and warning: `destination with the same identifier (name{Hfootnote.3}) has been already used, duplicate ignored`). So the `\xdef` makes it so that the anchor automatically placed by `\footnotetext` is a dummy one that doesn't conflict with the ones we explicitly place using `\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { }`.

Comment: @frougon Thank you for the explanation, however I don't know why I didn't get this warning on my side (or is it only a message in the log file?). By the way, in your first sentence, did you mean `\clist_clear:N \l_tmpb_clist` is missing?

Comment: @Jinwen I already corrected the `\clist_clear:N \l_tmpb_clist` (copy/paste error :). Regarding the warning, it's in the log file and on the standard output, after at least two compilation runs. It doesn't start with `!`; don't trust editors that filter the errors!

Comment: For nicer target location, `\Hy@raisedlink { \hypertarget{\getrefbykeydefault{##1}{anchor}{Doc-Start}}{} }` seems to help.

Comment: The main ideas in this code are IMHO: 1) `hyperref`'s redefinition of `\footnotemark` leaves an anchor name (associated to the value of the `Hfootnote` counter) in `\Hy@footnote@currentHref`. 2) `hyperref`'s `\label` redefinition writes the anchor name contained in `\@currentHref` to the .aux file (via `\newlabel`), associating it with the provided label.

Comment: 3) Using the `refcount` package (I think `hyperref` always loads it), `\getrefbykeydefault{⟨label⟩}{anchor}{⟨default⟩}` allows one to retrieve the anchor associated with ⟨label⟩ and place this anchor in the footnote text using `\hypertarget`. 4) Because of this explicit setting of the desired anchor, we disable the automatic anchor placed by `hyperref`'s `\@footnotetext` (which avoids duplicates).

Comment: Note: the anchor automatically placed by `hyperref`'s `\@footnotetext` is named after the contents of `\Hy@footnote@currentHref` so that calling `\@footnotemark` followed by `\@footnotetext` creates a hyperlink from the mark to the footnote (a `\footnote` call does exactly this: it is the documented case where `hyperref` can reliably and automatically create a hyperlink from the footnote mark to the footnote).

Comment: Final remark: IMHO, the code should review its use of optional arguments and `\tl_if_blank:nF`. First because trailing optional arguments are slightly evil (they can cause bad surprises) and `\multifootnotemark` isn't useful without its argument. Second because there are logical errors in `\multifootnotetext` when its optional argument is blank: (a) The `\xdef \Hy@footnote@currentHref { x\Hy@footnote@currentHref }` is still done, but this doesn't make much sense in this case. (b) `\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { }` is also issued, however `\l_tmpb_clist` hasn't been initialized in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much simpler and convenient approach IMO.

Instead of making unique footnotes to specify them later as a comma separated list (`fn1,fn2,fn3`), I'd suggest create ID system for grouped footnotes i.e

- Whenever you need to combine several footnotes, choose an `<id>`
- And now, instead of ordinary `\footnote` use `\footnoteid{<id>}`
- After that, using another macro `\addfootnotegroup{<id>}{<text>}` you add it to the actual footnote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\footnoteid}[1]{%
    {\footnotemark\def\thefootnote{}\footnotetext{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}}%
    \ifcsname gfnt#1\endcsname
        \expandafter\xdef\csname gfnt#1\endcsname{\csname gfnt#1\endcsname,\thefootnote}%
    \else
        \expandafter\xdef\csname gfnt#1\endcsname{\thefootnote}%
    \fi
}
\newcommand{\addfootnotegroup}[2]{%
    {\def\thefootnote{\csname gfnt#1\endcsname}\footnotetext{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
Lorem\footnote{default} ipsum dolor sit amet\footnoteid{idI}, consectetur\footnote{another} adipiscing\footnoteid{idI} elit\footnoteid{idI}.

\addfootnotegroup{idI}{grouped footnote}

Lorem ipsum\footnote{one more} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{document}
```

[image]

It  works both with and without `hyperref` package.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed a great idea! Would you mind if I integrate this into the package `multifootnote` as the primary way for writing such a footnote? (I'm thinking of permitting the `<id>` here as a comma list, thus e.g. footnote for `1,2,3` then for `1,4,5` is possible, though it might be a rare usage case. When it's finished I shall post another answer below.)

Comment: @Jinwen sure, go ahead. If you could give credit as a comment in the `.sty`, it would be preferable thought.

Comment: Thank you. I shall mention in the section "Acknowledgements" of the documentation that this method came from you. Shall I refer to you as "antshar" or do you prefer otherwise?

Comment: @Jinwen You can use my TeX.SE name for that, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer's wonderful answer and Frougon's useful comments under it, below is the updated version of these two commands, work either with or without `hyperref`.

```
\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotemark { O{} }
  {
    \footnotemark
    \group_begin:
      \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
        {
          \addtocounter { footnote } { -1 }
          \refstepcounter { footnote }
          \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
            {
              \cs_gset_eq:NN \@currentHref \Hy@footnote@currentHref
            } {}
          \label { #1 }
        }
    \group_end:
  }
\NewCommandCopy \footnotenumber \multifootnotemark

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetext { O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
      {
        \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
        \clist_clear:N \l_tmpb_clist
        \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
          {
            \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
              {
                \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
                  { \ref*{ ##1 } }
                \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_clist
                  { \Hy@raisedlink { \hypertarget { \getrefbykeydefault{##1}{anchor}{Doc-Start} } {} } }
              }
              {
                \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
                  { \ref{ ##1 } }
              }
          }
        \def \thefootnote { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { , } }
      }
    \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
      {
        \xdef \Hy@footnote@currentHref { x\Hy@footnote@currentHref }
      } {}
    \footnotetext { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpb_clist {} \ignorespaces #2 }
    \group_end:
  }
\NewCommandCopy \multifootnote \multifootnotetext
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the `expl3` version of @antshar's approach. A minor improvement here is that the `<id>` can be a comma-separated list, thus for example footnote for `1,2,3` then for `1,4,5` is possible (though it might be a rare usage case).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage{footnotebackref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnoteid { m }
  {
    \footnotemark
    \group_begin:
      \def \thefootnote {}
      \footnotetext { \vspace { -\baselineskip } }
    \group_end:
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
        \cs_if_exist:cTF { multifootnote ##1 }
          {
            \tl_gput_right:cx { multifootnote ##1 } { , \thefootnote }
          }
          {
            \cs_gset:cpx { multifootnote ##1 } { \thefootnote }
          }
      }
  }
\NewCommandCopy \footnoteid \multifootnoteid

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotegroup { m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \def \thefootnote { \use:c { multifootnote #1 } }
      \footnotetext { #2 }
    \group_end:
  }
\NewCommandCopy \footnotegroup \multifootnotegroup

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum\footnoteid{idI,idII} dolor sit amet\footnoteid{idI}, consectetur\footnoteid{idII} adipiscing elit\footnoteid{idI}.
\footnotegroup{idI}{Test footnote 1.}
\footnotegroup{idII}{Test footnote 2.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]